# Pronunciation of 'oo' (in AE)

Tags: pronunciation

I have a hard time trying to get my pronunciation of words like *hood*, *book*, *hooker*, or *wood* right. I was wondering, is the 'oo' sound in these words pronounced exactly the same as in *good*? If so, that would make it a fair bit easier for me.

Comment: Dictionaries list approximations of the pronunciations of words.  So look them up.  Unfortunately, in American (or even British) English, the 'oo' spelling is not always pronounced the same.  And even AE is not a monolithic thing, there are differences of pronunciations throughout the continent.

Comment: I'd say yes, but I wouldn't say that for words like _flood_ and _door_, or _hoop_ and _food_. You might also be interested to learned about a good Stack Exchange site for [ell.se].

Comment: All those words are considered to have the same sound. Of course, sounds vary a bit randomly even between two pronunciations of the same word, and surrounding sounds also affect the pronunciation of vowels. Before a consonant like "d", the same vowel sound will be physically longer than before a consonant like "k" or "t".

Comment: yes I pronounce them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a fairly neutral AE accent because I have moved quite a bit, with only a few dialect-type pronunciations that I am aware of. I sound all the words you listed in the same place in my mouth. I think if you pronounce them all with the same vowel sound as good, you would be in fine shape.